# How to store data permanently in android Q+

Tags: android

Recently, I watched a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UnJ3amzJM94&feature=youtu.be) which says starting from android 11 there will be huge storage restrictions.

For example, if I want to encrypt video, image, audio and save them in local storage, is there any way I can do it in later versions of android?

So, I want to save the encrypted data even if my app is unistalled.

Comment: For something like that, use the Storage Access Framework (`ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT`, etc.). I have a whole series of blog posts about it, starting with [this one](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/19/scoped-storage-stories-saf-basics.html). Also, this is covered in [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage) in [a few different places](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/use-cases).

Comment: Thank you very much! You blog posts really helped me to understand!